# Autoscroll an overflow element does not continue for multiple added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get an element to autoscroll to the bottom of an `overflow:auto` div when a new message is appended to a list via jquery `.append`

Currently it's achieved using:

```
$(".content-wrapper").scrollTop($(".messages").children().height());
```

and it works for the first two added elements however when I let it run for longer it then stops autoscrolling.

[The JS Fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/qanneac6/1/)

How can I make sure it continues to scroll after the first two added messages?

Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must get the `scrollHeight`: `$(".content")[0].scrollHeight`

So you change your code to this:

```
$(".content-wrapper").scrollTop($(".content")[0].scrollHeight);
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qanneac6/6/)

Comment: Thanks FcoRodr - this solution works on Firefox, but not chrome ... do you have any idea why?

Comment: @TomHill I couldn't find the reason for not to work in Chrome, but fortunately it seems to work if you get the `scrollHeight` from the `div.content` like this `$(".content")[0].scrollHeight`. I'm going to edit my answer.